# Element-wise sum of arrays across multiple columns of a data frame in Spark / Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Dataframe that can have multiple columns of Array type like "Array1", "Array2" ... etc. These array columns would have same number of elements. I need to compute a new column of Array type which will be the sum of arrays element wise. How can I do it ?

Spark version = 2.3

For Ex:

Input:

```
|Column1| ... |ArrayColumn2|ArrayColumn3|
|-------| --- |------------|------------|
|T1     | ... |[1, 2 , 3]  | [2, 5, 7]
```

Output:

```
|Column1| ... |AggregatedColumn|
|-------| --- |------------|
|T1.    | ... |[3, 7 , 10]
```

No of Array columns are not fixed, thus I need a generalized solution. I would have a list of columns for which I would need to aggregate.

Thanks !

Comment: will all array columns have same number of elements ?

Comment: Yes, array columns will have same number of elements. I would update the question clarifying this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `inline` and higher-order function `aggregate` (available in Spark 2.4+) to compute element-wise sums from the Array-typed columns, followed by a `groupBy/agg` to group the element-wise sums back into Arrays:

```
val df = Seq(
  (101, Seq(1, 2), Seq(3, 4), Seq(5, 6)),
  (202, Seq(7, 8), Seq(9, 10), Seq(11, 12))
).toDF("id", "arr1", "arr2", "arr3")

val arrCols = df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("arr")).map(col)
```

**For Spark 3.0+**

```
df.
  withColumn("arr_structs", arrays_zip(arrCols: _*)).
  select($"id", expr("inline(arr_structs)")).
  select($"id", aggregate(array(arrCols: _*), lit(0), (acc, x) => acc + x).as("pos_elem_sum")).
  groupBy("id").agg(collect_list($"pos_elem_sum").as("arr_elem_sum")).
  show
// +---+------------+
// | id|arr_elem_sum|
// +---+------------+
// |101|     [9, 12]|
// |202|    [27, 30]|
// +---+------------+
```

**For Spark 2.4+**

```
df.
  withColumn("arr_structs", arrays_zip(arrCols: _*)).
  select($"id", expr("inline(arr_structs)")).
  select($"id", array(arrCols: _*).as("arr_pos_elems")).
  select($"id", expr("aggregate(arr_pos_elems, 0, (acc, x) -> acc + x)").as("pos_elem_sum")).
  groupBy("id").agg(collect_list($"pos_elem_sum").as("arr_elem_sum")).
  show
```

**For Spark 2.3 or below**

```
val sumArrElems = udf{ (arr: Seq[Int]) => arr.sum }

df.
  withColumn("arr_structs", arrays_zip(arrCols: _*)).
  select($"id", expr("inline(arr_structs)")).
  select($"id", sumArrElems(array(arrCols: _*)).as("pos_elem_sum")).
  groupBy("id").agg(collect_list($"pos_elem_sum").as("arr_elem_sum")).
  show
```

Comment: @Diamondhead, just noticed you had specified being on Spark 2.3.  Answer expanded to cover various Spark versions.

Answer (score 1):

An SQL expression like `array(ArrayColumn2[0]+ArrayColumn3[0], ArrayColumn2[1]+...)` can used to calulate the expected result.

```scala
val df = ...

//get all array columns
val arrayCols = df.schema.fields.filter(_.dataType.isInstanceOf[ArrayType]).map(_.name)

//get the size of the first array of the first row
val firstArray = arrayCols(0)
val arraySize = df.selectExpr(s"size($firstArray)").first().getAs[Int](0)

//generate the sql expression for the sums
val sums = (for( i <-0 to arraySize-1)
  yield arrayCols.map(c=>s"$c[$i]").mkString("+")).mkString(",")
//sums = ArrayColumn2[0]+ArrayColumn3[0],ArrayColumn2[1]+ArrayColumn3[1],ArrayColumn2[2]+ArrayColumn3[2]

//create a new column using sums
df.withColumn("AggregatedColumn", expr(s"array($sums)")).show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+------------+------------+----------------+
|Column1|ArrayColumn2|ArrayColumn3|AggregatedColumn|
+-------+------------+------------+----------------+
|     T1|   [1, 2, 3]|   [2, 5, 7]|      [3, 7, 10]|
+-------+------------+------------+----------------+
```

Using this single (long) SQL expression will avoid shuffling data over the network and thus improve performance.